# Get text with newlines between two words in bash

Tags: xml, bash

I have a standard .Net .csproj xml file that contains xml tags and text between them like this:

```
<lorem>ipsum</lorem>
<PackageReleaseNotes>Some information.

- Some more information.</PackageReleaseNotes>
<lorem>ipsum</lorem>
```

I need a bash command that will extract the text, newlines and all, between the `<PackageReleaseNotes>` and `</PackageReleaseNotes>` tags.

I came up with `cat Useful.String.Extensions.csproj | grep -o -P '(?<=PackageReleaseNotes>).*(?=</PackageReleaseNotes>)'` and it works if the text between the tags does not have newlines. But for the case I used as an example, it returns nothing.

Comment: Use a tool like `xmlstarlet` for processing XML files.

Comment: [You can't parse \[X\]HTML with regex](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/3776858). I suggest to use an XML/HTML parser (xmlstarlet, e.g.).

Comment: I don't know why everyone says you can't parse xml or whatever with regex. The accepted answer is EXACTLY what I am looking for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
cat Useful.String.Extensions.csproj | grep -Pzo '(?<=PackageReleaseNotes>)(.|\n)*(?=</PackageReleaseNotes>)'
```

```
-z/--null-data 
Treat input and output data as sequences of lines.
```

Comment: What does `-z/--null-data 
Treat input and output data as sequences of lines.` mean?

Comment: Why the `cat` ?

Comment: It was this way in the OP, I don't know how exactly OP wants to tweak it, hence I only applied change to the second part. You can pass filename to grep, of course.